# Editing a file by adding a prefix at specific places

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have a file which looks like this:

```
fixedStep chrom=20 start=1 step=1000   
0   
10   
20   
100   
0  
fixedStep chrom=19 start=1 step=1000   
0   
0   
50   
330   
450   
0
```

I want to add a prefix `chr` to the number which comes after `chrom=`. Therefor, instead of having `chrom=20` or `chrom=19`, I want to have `chrom=chr20`or `chrom=chr20`. So the file should look like this:

```
fixedStep chrom=chr20 start=1 step=1000   
0   
10   
20   
100   
0  
fixedStep chrom=chr19 start=1 step=1000   
0   
0   
50   
330   
450   
0
```

I know that with `sed`command I will be able to do this, but what I don't know is how to construct a `regex`which finds the `chrom=`part. I had already used `sed`to modify simple things like adding a prefix to the beginning of each line in a file; but I cannot wrap my mind around this question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
sed 's/\(chrom=\)/\1chr/g' file
fixedStep chrom=chr20 start=1 step=1000
0
10
20
100
0
fixedStep chrom=chr19 start=1 step=1000
0
0
50
330
450
0
```

`\(chrom=\)` searches `chrom=` and captures it in a group #1 to be used in replacement pattern `\1chr`.

Or else even simpler:

```
sed 's/chrom=/&chr/g' file
```

Comment: Cool! It worked! I will accept this as the answer as soon as `stackoverflow` lets me to do so, apparently, I have to wait another 10 minutes! 
By the way, is there any tutorial on the web on learning how to construct such complex regex? Thanks in advance for your response. :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. [gnu's official doc on sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: Just a suggestion: `sed 's/chrom=/&chr/g'`

Comment: Thanks @jaba10: I edited answer to add that as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/chrom=/chrom=chr/' filename
```

Output:

```
fixedStep chrom=chr20 start=1 step=1000   
0   
10   
20   
100   
0  
fixedStep chrom=chr19 start=1 step=1000   
0   
0   
50   
330   
450   
0
```